# Title on a multi-panel plot

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization

The following code works perfectly, except for the last line, which appears to be ignored. The code creates a dataframe consisting of three columns and then proceeds to plot the columns on a 2x2 grid. The last line is supposed to give a title to the entire multi-panel plot. However, it has no effect on the outcome. What is wrong? How can I correct it?

```
p <- c(3, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100)
n <- c(100, 5000, 100000)
f <- function(x, y){ return ((1 - 2^(-1/y))^(1/x))}

d <- as.data.frame(outer(p, n, FUN = f))
dimnames(d) <- list(p, n)

par(mfrow = c(2,2))    
lapply(colnames(d),
       function(x) plot(p, d[,x], type = "b",
                        main = paste("#points = ", x),
                        xlab = "Dim",
                        ylab = "Med Dist"))
mtext("Densities", outer = TRUE, cex = 1.5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
par(oma = c(0, 0, 2, 0))
par(mfrow = c(2,2))    
lapply(colnames(d),
      function(x) plot(p, d[,x], type = "b",
                    main = paste("#points = ", x),
                    xlab = "Dim",
                    ylab = "Med Dist"))
title("Densities", outer=TRUE)
```

Comment: @EvanAad - note that `mtext` would also work here. The important step is adding an outer margin to side 3.